# My drawer list adapter throws class cast exception in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

Hy guys. I have problem with my navigation drawer list. Problem occur when I want to update one item of my drawer list. When user click one of the checkboxes, I want to update one item in my drawer list. If user doesn't click on one of the checkboxes, drawer list works fine, but when he clicks on of them, and user swipes over the screen to show the drawer list, when he click on one of the items, application crashes. Can you help me to find a good solution to update one item of my drawer list. Only need to change image in imageview. I tryed to solve this whole day, but I can't find solutions, can you help me. I appreciate your help. Thank you.
Here is my main activity

```
public class PitanjeActivity extends NavDrawerActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
private int mShortAnimationDuration;

private ArrayList<Pitanja> getAllPitanja;
private ArrayList<Pitanje_has_Slika> getAllImages;
private ArrayList<Odgovor> odgovorList;
private HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> odgBrojPitanja;
private List<Integer> kliknuti;
private DBTools db = new DBTools(this);
private Intent intent;
int broj = 0;
private ImageView previous, informacije, odgovori, next, textSlike;
private TextView brojPitanja, kategorijaPitanja, textPitanja;
private String info;
private ListView listView;
boolean odgovoreno, tocno;
private RelativeLayout rightRL;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> m;
PitanjaAdapter adapter;



@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previousButton);

    informacije = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.informacijeButton);
    odgovori = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.odgovoriButton);
    next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    textSlike = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSlikaImageView);
    brojPitanja = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brojPitanjaTextViewPitanjeActivity);
    kategorijaPitanja = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kategorijaTextViewPitanjeActivity);
    kategorijaPitanja.setText(intent.getStringExtra("NAZIV_KATEGORIJE"));
    textPitanja = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPitanjaTextViewPitanjaActivity);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    informacije.setOnClickListener(this);
    odgovori.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

    getAllImages = db.getAllPitanjaImages();
    odgBrojPitanja = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

    updateDisplay(broj);

}

@Override
protected void onNavItemSelected(int id) {

    if ( id > 200){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kliknuo si na pitanje" + id + " toliki je id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateDisplay(id-200-1);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kliknuo si na izbornik" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected NavDrawerActivityConfiguration getNavDrawerConfiguration() {

    intent = getIntent();
    getAllPitanja = db
            .getAllPitanja(intent.getStringExtra("id_kategorije"));

    m = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    m.add(NavigationItem.create(100, "Profil", R.drawable.ikona_profil_bez_okvira_01_01, this));
    m.add(NavigationItem.create(200, "Teme", R.drawable.ikona_kategorije_bez_okvira_01_01,this));
    m.add(NavigationItem.create(300, "Ispiti", R.drawable.ikona_ispit_bez_okvira_01, this));
    m.add(NavigationItem.create(400, "Znakovi", R.drawable.ikona_znakovi_bez_okvira_01, this));
    m.add(new NavigationSection(200, "PITANJA"));
    for (int i=0;i<getAllPitanja.size();i++){
        m.add(NavigationPitanja.create((200+i+1), "Pitanje " + (i+1), getAllPitanja.get(i).getTextPitanja(), this));
    }


    NavDrawerActivityConfiguration navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration = new NavDrawerActivityConfiguration();
    navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration.setLayout(R.layout.activity_pitanje);
    navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration.setDrawerLayoutId(R.id.drawer_layout_pitanja);
    navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration.setLeftDrawer(R.id.listaDesnoPitanja);
    navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration.setNavigationItem(m);
    navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration.setBaseAdapter(new NavigationListAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, m));
    return navDrawerActivityCOnfiguration;

}

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public void updateDisplay(int z) {

    odgovoreno = false;
    tocno = true;
    brojPitanja.setText(String.valueOf(z + 1) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(getAllPitanja.size()));
    textPitanja.setText(stripHtml(String.valueOf(getAllPitanja.get(z).getTextPitanja())));
    textSlike.setImageBitmap(null);
    info = getAllPitanja.get(z).getInfo();

    Log.d("Postoji", getAllImages.get(z).getNazivSlike() + ", ");

    for (int j = 0; j < getAllImages.size(); j++) {
        if (getAllImages.get(j).getIdPitanja() == getAllPitanja.get(z)
                .getIdPitanja()
                && getAllImages.get(j).getNazivSlike() != null) {
            Log.i("Id pitanja slike + idpitanja pitanja + idSlike",
                    getAllImages.get(j).getIdPitanja()
                            + ", "
                            + String.valueOf(getAllPitanja.get(z)
                                    .getIdPitanja()
                                    + ", "
                                    + getAllImages.get(j).getIdSlika()));
            textSlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String uri = PregledZnakova.PHOTOS_BASE_URL
                    + getAllImages.get(j).getNazivSlike();
            int rounded_value = 40;    

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(rounded_value)).build();
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();               
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); 
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, textSlike,options);


            textSlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    zoomImage(textSlike, textSlike);

                }
            });
            break;
            // }

        } else {
            textSlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

    odgovorList = db.getAllOdgovore(Integer.toString(getAllPitanja.get(z)
            .getIdPitanja()));
    adapter = new PitanjaAdapter(this,
            R.layout.pitanja_entry, odgovorList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (checkList(z) == true){
        checList(z);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<getAllPitanja.size();i++){
        if (getAllPitanja.get(i).isTocno()){
            Log.i("Ovo pitanje je tocno", getAllPitanja.get(i).getTextPitanja());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.previousButton:
        odgovoreno = check();
        if (odgovoreno) {
            updateOdgovor(broj);
            set();
        } else {
            broj--;
            if (broj < 0) {
                broj = getAllPitanja.size() - 1;
            }
            updateDisplay(broj);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.informacijeButton:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                InformacijeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Informacije", info);
        intent.putExtra("naslov",
                String.valueOf(getAllPitanja.get(broj).getTextPitanja()));
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.odgovoriButton:
        updateOdgovor(broj);
        postaviPitanje(broj);
        set();
        break;

    case R.id.nextButton:
        odgovoreno = check();
        if (odgovoreno) {
            updateOdgovor(broj);
            set();
        } else {
            broj++;
            if (broj > (getAllPitanja.size() - 1)) {
                broj = 0;
            }
            updateDisplay(broj);
        }

        break;

    }
}

public String stripHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}

private boolean check() {
    for (int i = 0; i < odgovorList.size(); i++) {
        Odgovor o = odgovorList.get(i);
        if (o.isSelected())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void checList(int a) {

    for (int i = 0; i < odgovorList.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("Velicina odgovorList je  ", String.valueOf((odgovorList.size())));
        Odgovor odgovor = odgovorList.get(i);

        for (List<Integer> tocan_odgovor : odgBrojPitanja.values()) {

            if (tocan_odgovor.contains(odgovor.getId())) {
                odgovor.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
        adapter.colorized(odgovor);
    }

}

private boolean checkList(int a){

    List<Integer> value = odgBrojPitanja.get(a);
    if (value != null){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

private void set() {

    for (int i = 0; i < odgovorList.size(); i++) {
        Odgovor o = odgovorList.get(i);
        o.setSelected(false);
    }

}

private void postaviPitanje(int z) {

    for (int i = 0; i < odgovorList.size(); i++) {
        Odgovor odgovor = odgovorList.get(i);
        if (Integer.parseInt(odgovor.getIs_correct()) == 0
                && odgovor.isSelected()
                || Integer.parseInt(odgovor.getIs_correct()) == 1
                && !odgovor.isSelected()) {
            tocno = false;
        }

    }
    if (tocno){
        getAllPitanja.get(z).setTocno(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tocno ste odgovorili na pitanje cij je id " + getAllPitanja.get(z).getIdPitanja() + 200, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Sljedeci mjenjeam", String.valueOf(200+getAllPitanja.get(z).getIdPitanja()));
        m.set(z, NavigationPitanja.update(200+getAllPitanja.get(z).getIdPitanja(), R.drawable.correct, this));
    }
    else {
        getAllPitanja.get(z).setNetocno(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Niste tocno odgovorili", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Here is my abstract class NavDrawerActivity

```
public abstract class NavDrawerActivity extends FragmentActivity{


private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
protected abstract void onNavItemSelected (int id);
private NavDrawerActivityConfiguration navConf;
protected abstract NavDrawerActivityConfiguration getNavDrawerConfiguration();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    navConf = getNavDrawerConfiguration();
    setContentView(navConf.getLayout());
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(navConf.getDrawerLayoutId());
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(navConf.getLeftDrawer());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(navConf.getBaseAdapter());
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

protected DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
    return mDrawerLayout;
}
public void selectItem (int position) {
    ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> selectedItem = navConf.getNavigationItem();
    //NavDrawerItem selectedItem = navConf.getNavItems()[position];
    this.onNavItemSelected(selectedItem.get(position).getId());
    //this.onNavItemSelected(selectedItem.getId());
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    if (this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(this.mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);

    }

}   
}
```

Just in case if you needed here is my NavigationPitanjaclass, the class where I want to change image of my imageview

```
public class NavigationPitanja implements NavDrawerItem{


public static final int PITANJA_TYPE = 2;
private int id;
private String naslov, text;
private int icon;

private NavigationPitanja(){

}

public static NavigationPitanja create(int id, String naslov, String text, Context context){

    NavigationPitanja pitanja = new NavigationPitanja();
    pitanja.setId(id);
    pitanja.setNaslov(naslov);
    pitanja.setText(text);
    return pitanja;

}

public static NavigationPitanja update(int id, int icon, Context context){
    NavigationPitanja pitanja = new NavigationPitanja();
    pitanja.setId(id);
    pitanja.setIcon(icon);
    return pitanja;
}

public String getNaslov() {
    return naslov;
}

public void setNaslov(String naslov) {
    this.naslov = naslov;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id;
}

@Override
public String getLabel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PITANJA_TYPE;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

}
```

and here is my adapter, where my log cat says that error ocurs

```
public class NavigationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavDrawerItem>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public NavigationListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    NavDrawerItem menuItem = this.getItem(position);
    if (menuItem.getType() == NavigationItem.ITEM_TYPE) {
        view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    } 
    else if (menuItem.getType() == NavigationPitanja.PITANJA_TYPE){
        view = getPitanjaView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    }
    else {
        view = getSectionView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    }
    return view;
}

public View getItemView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavigationItem menuItem = (NavigationItem) navDrawerItem;
    NavMenuItemHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parentView,
                false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenuitem_label);
        ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenuitem_icon);

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuItemHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView;
        navMenuItemHolder.image = i;

        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if (navMenuItemHolder == null) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuItem.getLabel().toString());
    navMenuItemHolder.image.setImageResource(menuItem.getIcon());

    return convertView;
}

public View getSectionView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavigationSection menuSection = (NavigationSection) navDrawerItem;
    NavMenuSectionHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.darwer_list_section,
                parentView, false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenusection_label);

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuSectionHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView;
        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if (navMenuItemHolder == null) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuSectionHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuSection.getLabel().toString());

    return convertView;
}

public View getPitanjaView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView, NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem){

    NavigationPitanja pitanjaSection = (NavigationPitanja) navDrawerItem;
    NavMenuPitanjaHolder navMenuPitanjaHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_pitanja, parentView, false);
        TextView naslovView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.naslovPitanja);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPitanja);
        ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tocno_netocno_imageView);

        navMenuPitanjaHolder = new NavMenuPitanjaHolder();
        navMenuPitanjaHolder.naslovPitanja = naslovView;
        navMenuPitanjaHolder.textPitanja = textView;
        navMenuPitanjaHolder.image = i;
        convertView.setTag(navMenuPitanjaHolder);

    }

    if (navMenuPitanjaHolder == null) {
        navMenuPitanjaHolder = (NavMenuPitanjaHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuPitanjaHolder.naslovPitanja.setText(pitanjaSection.getNaslov().toString());
    navMenuPitanjaHolder.textPitanja.setText(pitanjaSection.getText().toString());
    if (pitanjaSection.getIcon() == 0)
        navMenuPitanjaHolder.image.setImageResource(pitanjaSection.getIcon());

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return this.getItem(position).getType();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isEnabled();
}


private static class NavMenuItemHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
    private ImageView image;
}

private static class NavMenuSectionHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
}

private static class NavMenuPitanjaHolder {
    private TextView naslovPitanja, textPitanja;
    private ImageView image;
}


}
```

here is my logcat

> 01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.prolink.autoskola.adapter.NavigationListAdapter$NavMenuItemHolder cannot be cast to com.prolink.autoskola.adapter.NavigationListAdapter$NavMenuPitanjaHolder
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.prolink.autoskola.adapter.NavigationListAdapter.getPitanjaView(NavigationListAdapter.java:121)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.prolink.autoskola.adapter.NavigationListAdapter.getView(NavigationListAdapter.java:37)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2449)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:642)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5535)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3417)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3911)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7350)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2412)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2147)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2139)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1476)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2087)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7535)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3415)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3347)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4456)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4538)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4506)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4557)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   01-29 21:50:07.815: E/AndroidRuntime(13414):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any help is welcome, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### **how u want to cast it?**

```
 private static class NavMenuItemHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
    private ImageView image;
}

private static class NavMenuPitanjaHolder {
    private TextView naslovPitanja, textPitanja;
    private ImageView image;
}
```

**CONSIDER THIS: IS EVERY CAR A TRUCK???**

[image]